Regex to match alternating words & numbers with specific char restrictions
I'm trying to match a pattern in a string where the string alternates between words and numbers (e.g., "apple 123 orange 4567"), words can only contain letters (both upper and lower case) and numbers can have varying lengths, but must contain only digits.
Example:
apple 123 orange 4567
banana 8 pineapple 999

But I want to exclude cases e.g.,
apple123 4567, 123apple 123

I tried \b[a-zA-Z]+\s\d+\b. This works for individual word-number pairs, but it doesn’t ensure the entire string alternates between a word and a number. Additionally, it doesn't prevent sequences like apple123 or 123apple. How can I modify the regex to ensure the string alternates between words and numbers, exclude mixed word-number sequences and match this pattern across the whole string, not just isolated pairs?

Why can't you write a simple piece of code instead of using a complex Regex?

I'm just practicing regular expressions?

Yeah, that's fine. To me, Regex are seldom the solution. They help me a lot, but I never used one in code. Why? Because they always mess up, like yours. There's always an edge case which you miss and a piec of code covers that much better.

It's at least good to understand the concept and to know how to write a regex. I'm not an expert myself I'm just learning.

what about this (?:[a-zA-Z]+\s+[0-9]+(\s+)?)+ I am not quite sure what you need this for. But if you can split each line then go with answer from Thomas below.

Now you have two problems.

Look at all the answers. Is it possible to understand any of those Regexes? And even my answer was incorrect (look at the comment and the edit history). Whenever you need to think more than 3 minutes about a Regex, code is better.
test_cases=["apple    123 \n orange \t\v 4567", "apple123 4567, 123apple 123"]
for test_case in test_cases:
    terms = test_case.split()
    words = terms[0::2]
    numbers = terms[1::2]
    for word in words:
        if not word.isalpha():
            print(word + " is not a word")
    for number in numbers:
        if not number.isdigit():
            print(number + " is not a number")


op asks for " but it doesn’t ensure the entire string alternates between a word and a number." With findall you can only filter all appeareances where a alpahbetic word is followed by a number, but if there is a alphanumeric word between such pairs, this apporach will not mark the whole string as invalid. Or do I miss something? I am not that familiar with pythons re-module.

Here is an example that should do what you want.
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(\b[a-zA-Z]+\s\d+\b\s?)+((?<=\s)[a-zA-Z]+)?")

assert bool(re.fullmatch(pattern, "apple 123 orange 4567"))
assert bool(re.fullmatch(pattern, "banana 8 pineapple 999"))
assert not bool(re.fullmatch(pattern, "apple123 4567, 123apple 123"))
assert not bool(re.fullmatch(pattern, "banana 8 pineapple999"))
assert bool(re.fullmatch(pattern, "apple 123 orange 4567 banana"))

To break the regex a little bit down:
The first part (\b[a-zA-Z]+\s\d+\b\s?)+ is quite the same as what you have posted.
Match pairs that start with word boundarie followed by word followed by a single whitespace followed by a number followed by word boundarie, maybe followed by a whitespace, repeat.
This plus the re.fullmatch fullfills the requirements your example gives.

But, you have also tagged with python, so here are some problems, this solution has, that are uncovered at the moment, which I have tried to solve with regexes (the second part of statement) but I gave up, and recomend, as also stated by comments, no complex regexes, you and any other have fun with them if the documentation is bad to regenineer them.
So here are the problems:

What if there is a whitespace at the end of string?
What if there are multiple whitespaces between the single tokens (word or numbers)
What if your string ends with a word and no number?
What if your string starts with a number?

The third problem is the second part ((?<=\s)[a-zA-Z]+)?, Problem 1, 2 and 4 break this regex.
the outer braces and the ? make the whole part optional.
(?<=\s) checks if the last sign the regex engine read is a whitespace. The concept is called positive lookbehind.
And the rest is your check word logic.

If you do not know such websites, there are many out there like this one. I will recommend regex101.com.
It supports many different regex engines, because the same regex can create different results in different engines. It also explains what your own regex does and it shows you all possible commands you have to create your regexes, with explanation and examples.
For transparency, I recommend this website because I have learned regexes with it and never tried another.

But here comes a maybe simpler to understand example, that you should use in production code. (I know you want to learn regex and this is a good reason to build such complex regexes, but a lesson I had also to learn is: Do not use those regexes in some code that is not a throw away peace of code.)
And this code should also address all four problems from above.
import re

def validate_input(input: str) -> bool:
    # make a list that contains only single words
    split = re.split("\s+", input.strip())

    # handle inputs that contain only whitespaces
    if not split:
        return False

    # helper function to handle the case, that we do not know if we start
    # with word or number.
    def give_check_fn(first, second):
        while True:
            yield first
            yield second

    if split[0].isalpha():
        gen = give_check_fn(str.isalpha, str.isnumeric)
    else:
        gen = give_check_fn(str.isnumeric, str.isalpha)

    for value, check_fn in zip(split, gen):
        if not check_fn(value):
            return False
    return True

assert validate_input("123 banana \n 8 \t pineapple    999 apple ")
assert not validate_input("apple 123 apple123 banana 4")


To assure the entire line matches your pairs, you need to do two things:

Deal with the delimiter separating the pairs, in this case a horizontal space and;
Add anchors for the beginning and end of the lines.

You can use:
^(?:\b[a-zA-Z]+[ \t]\d+\b[ \t]?){1,}$ # one or more..

# If you want a total of 2 pairs only:
^(?:\b[a-zA-Z]+[ \t]\d+\b[ \t]?){2}$

Demo
Python demo:
import re 

txt='''\
apple 123 orange 4567
banana 8 pineapple 999
apple123 4567 123apple 123
apple 123 apple123
'''

for line in txt.splitlines():
    print(re.match(r'^(?:\b[a-zA-Z]+[0 \t]\d+\b[ \t]?){1,}$', line))

Prints:
<re.Match object; span=(0, 21), match='apple 123 orange 4567'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 22), match='banana 8 pineapple 999'>
None
None


To match a string that alternates between words and numbers, assuming that it starts with a word consisting of characters A-Za-z without any leading or trailing spaces:
^[A-Za-z]+[^\S\n]+\d+(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Za-z]+[^\S\n]+\d+)*$

The pattern matches:

^ Start of string
[A-Za-z]+ Match 1+ chars A-Za-z
[^\S\n]+ Match 1+ whitespace chars without newlines
\d+ Match 1+ digits
(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Za-z]+[^\S\n]+\d+)* Repeat the same starting pattern 0+ times using a non capture group (?:...)*
$ End of string

See a regex demo.
If there can be leading or trailing spaces:
^[^\S\n]*(?:[A-Za-z]+[^\S\n]+\d+\b[^\S\n]*)+$

This pattern starts with optional spaces, then repeats the "words and numbers" part 1 or more times where the numbers are followed by optional spaces and the word boundary \b prevents a digit being followed by a char A-Za-z
See another regex demo.
